# numba @jit(nopython=True): Refactor function that uses dictionary with lists as values

Tags: python, design-patterns, refactoring, numba

I have several functions that I want to use numba @jit(nopython=True) for, but they all rely on the following function:

```
def getIslands(labels2D,ignoreSea=True):
    islands = {}
    width = labels2D.shape[1]
    height = labels2D.shape[0]
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            label = labels2D[y,x]
            if ignoreSea and label == -1:
                continue
            if label in islands:
                islands[label].append((x,y))
            else:
                islands[label] = [(x,y)]
    return islands
```

Is there any way to redesign this function so it's compatible with numba @jit(nopython=True)? The JIT fails since the function uses features of python dictionaries that are not supported (i.e., dictionaries containing lists as values.)

numba==0.52.0

Comment: What is the type of the items in labels2D?

Comment: @JérômeRichard python built-in type `int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries and lists are not very user-friendly in Numba yet. You first need to declare the type of the dictionary values (outside the function):

```py
import numba as nb

intTupleList = nb.types.List(nb.types.UniTuple(nb.int_, 2))
```

Then you can create an empty typed dictionary in the function using `nb.typed.typeddict.Dict.empty`. The same thing applies for a list with `nb.typed.typedlist.List`. Here is how:

```py
@nb.njit('(int_[:,:], bool_)')
def getIslands(labels2D,ignoreSea=True):
    islands = nb.typed.typeddict.Dict.empty(key_type=nb.int_, value_type=intTupleList)
    width = labels2D.shape[1]
    height = labels2D.shape[0]
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            label = labels2D[y,x]
            if ignoreSea and label == -1:
                continue
            if label in islands:
                islands[label].append((np.int_(x),np.int_(y)))
            else:
                islands[label] = nb.typed.typedlist.List([(np.int_(x),np.int_(y))])
    return islands
```

This is a bit sad that Numba cannot infer the type of the list `[(x, y)]` yet since it is a bit painful to use `nb.typed.typedlist.List` (especially with the additional cast that are required because of the mismatch between the `nb.int_` type and loop iterators that are `nb.int64` on 64-bit machines.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try out your code in my project, with SO's attribution rules. Numba still hasn't reached version 1, so hopefully they will solve this issue in the future.